# nothing happens when i click upload files on channel files with channel form

Tags: devdemon, channel-files

Nothing happens when i click upload files on channel files with channel form

{exp:channel:form channel="news"}
{field:floor_plans}
{/exp:channel:form}

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the Q/A are both related to javascript, not ExpressionEngine.

Answer (score 1):

I found that it's a jquery conflict, I just remove the jquery include from script tag and it works.